# Merging many triangles into one mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I have a model which was constructed from individual triangles. I'd like to 'weld' the triangles into a mesh. Ultimatley, I'd like to weld them into contiguous parts, but if I could at least weld them into one mesh, I could theoretically separate by loose parts (right?). I really don't want to go through each group of coincident vertices, or edges, one by one. Is there a quick way to do this?
[image]

In this image, each of those faces is a separate face within the same mesh. I'd like to weld each set of coincident vertices in-place, so to speak, resulting in a nice minimal mesh, in this case resulting in 4 flared cone objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Edit mode for one one your "witches hats"
[image: Enter edit mode]

Press <kbd>a</kbd> to select all, or use the method of your choice to select **ALL** the verts around the figure. Notice 64 verts, 4 for each of 16 faces.
[image: Select all]

Press <kbd>m</kbd> for merge verts. Choose "By Distance"
[image: Merge verts]

There are now only 17 verts. Note the dialog that allows you to choose how close verts have to be to be merges. /me mumbles about floating point rounding errors...
[image: Fini]

When you've merged all the "witches hats" you can select them all in object mode and then press <kbd>j</kbd> to join the objects to a single mesh.